# How to increase Gaussian Blur strength in Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I found some great code here on SO and have implemented it in my app and although it is "working", the blur effect is not strong enough to actually realise (without focusing very hard on it) that it has actually blurred anything.

The code is (quite long, sorry):

```
    Bitmap screenshot = null;
    void BlurForm()
    {
        /*
         The best time (I assume) is to change the blur when the user as left the window,
         as opposed to doing it when they want to open the window, since this may be a 
         little intensive.
        */
        screenshot = null;
        blurred.Image = null; // This variable is the PictureBox that's on the Form

        screenshot = Screenshot.TakeSnapshot(this);
        BitmapFilter.GaussianBlur(screenshot, 4);

        blurred.Image = screenshot;
        blurred.SendToBack();
    }

    public class ConvMatrix
    {
        public int TopLeft = 0, TopMid = 0, TopRight = 0;
        public int MidLeft = 0, Pixel = 1, MidRight = 0;
        public int BottomLeft = 0, BottomMid = 0, BottomRight = 0;
        public int Factor = 1;
        public int Offset = 0;
        public void SetAll(int nVal)
        {
            TopLeft = TopMid = TopRight = MidLeft = Pixel = MidRight = BottomLeft = BottomMid = BottomRight = nVal;
        }
    }

    public class BitmapFilter
    {
        private static bool Conv3x3(Bitmap b, ConvMatrix m)
        {
            // Avoid divide by zero errors
            if (0 == m.Factor) return false;

            Bitmap bSrc = (Bitmap)b.Clone();

            // GDI+ still lies to us - the return format is BGR, NOT RGB.
            BitmapData bmData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            BitmapData bmSrc = bSrc.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bSrc.Width, bSrc.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            int stride = bmData.Stride;
            int stride2 = stride * 2;
            System.IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
            System.IntPtr SrcScan0 = bmSrc.Scan0;

            unsafe
            {
                byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
                byte* pSrc = (byte*)(void*)SrcScan0;

                int nOffset = stride + 6 - b.Width * 3;
                int nWidth = b.Width - 2;
                int nHeight = b.Height - 2;

                int nPixel;

                for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; ++y)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; ++x)
                    {
                        nPixel = ((((pSrc[2] * m.TopLeft) + (pSrc[5] * m.TopMid) + (pSrc[8] * m.TopRight) +
                            (pSrc[2 + stride] * m.MidLeft) + (pSrc[5 + stride] * m.Pixel) + (pSrc[8 + stride] * m.MidRight) +
                            (pSrc[2 + stride2] * m.BottomLeft) + (pSrc[5 + stride2] * m.BottomMid) + (pSrc[8 + stride2] * m.BottomRight)) / m.Factor) + m.Offset);

                        if (nPixel < 0) nPixel = 0;
                        if (nPixel > 255) nPixel = 255;

                        p[5 + stride] = (byte)nPixel;

                        nPixel = ((((pSrc[1] * m.TopLeft) + (pSrc[4] * m.TopMid) + (pSrc[7] * m.TopRight) +
                            (pSrc[1 + stride] * m.MidLeft) + (pSrc[4 + stride] * m.Pixel) + (pSrc[7 + stride] * m.MidRight) +
                            (pSrc[1 + stride2] * m.BottomLeft) + (pSrc[4 + stride2] * m.BottomMid) + (pSrc[7 + stride2] * m.BottomRight)) / m.Factor) + m.Offset);

                        if (nPixel < 0) nPixel = 0;
                        if (nPixel > 255) nPixel = 255;

                        p[4 + stride] = (byte)nPixel;

                        nPixel = ((((pSrc[0] * m.TopLeft) + (pSrc[3] * m.TopMid) + (pSrc[6] * m.TopRight) +
                            (pSrc[0 + stride] * m.MidLeft) + (pSrc[3 + stride] * m.Pixel) + (pSrc[6 + stride] * m.MidRight) +
                            (pSrc[0 + stride2] * m.BottomLeft) + (pSrc[3 + stride2] * m.BottomMid) + (pSrc[6 + stride2] * m.BottomRight)) / m.Factor) + m.Offset);

                        if (nPixel < 0) nPixel = 0;
                        if (nPixel > 255) nPixel = 255;

                        p[3 + stride] = (byte)nPixel;

                        p += 3;
                        pSrc += 3;
                    }

                    p += nOffset;
                    pSrc += nOffset;
                }
            }

            b.UnlockBits(bmData);
            bSrc.UnlockBits(bmSrc);

            return true;
        }

        public static bool GaussianBlur(Bitmap b, int nWeight /* default to 4*/)
        {
            ConvMatrix m = new ConvMatrix();
            m.SetAll(1);
            m.Pixel = nWeight;
            m.TopMid = m.MidLeft = m.MidRight = m.BottomMid = 2;
            m.Factor = nWeight + 12;

            return BitmapFilter.Conv3x3(b, m);
        }
    }

    class Screenshot
    {
        public static Bitmap TakeSnapshot(Control ctl)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ctl.Size.Width, ctl.Size.Height);
            using (Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(
                    ctl.PointToScreen(ctl.ClientRectangle.Location),
                    new Point(0, 0), ctl.ClientRectangle.Size
                );
            }
            return bmp;
        }
    }
```

I've tried changing every single value in there and it doesn't matter which value(s) I change, I just can't get it to have a stronger blur effect. How can I increase the strength of the Gaussian Blur?

The Form is 80% Opaque, so the blur effect you would see is the windows wallpaper or whatever is behind the form - but blurred. Only problem (as I've said) is that the blur is not strong at all.

Comment: The code is too primitive, use a [better library](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f074e0dd-865c-fd5f-ba0a-80e336a0eaea.htm).

Comment: @HansPassant can AForge be used in a commercial app?

Comment: It is LGPL as long as you stay away from video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After just glancing at the code, it looks to me like the blur filter is hardcoded to only operate in a 3x3 area at a time, severely restricting how blurred it can make an image.

Unless I'm mistaken, the only way to significantly increase the amount of blurring is to find a more sophisticated implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Smallhacker, I will keep searching around and see what I can come up with. I did read a comment somewhere on here and they said to make it have more blur you just need to keep adding another bitmap, but all that does is make it more opaque.